# In Java, How to fragment String according to Font.canDisplay method

Tags: java, string, list, fonts, java-stream

With a preferred font list given,[Main.main(...)](https://github.com/tugalsan/com.tugalsan.blg.file.tmcr/blob/main/src/main/java/com/tugalsan/blg/file/tmcr/Main.java)

```
//simplified code
List<java.awt.Font> preferredFontList = List.of(
  "Roboto-Regular.ttf", "FreeSerif.ttf", "Quivira-A8VL.ttf", "Code2000-rdLO.ttf"
).stream().map(fontName->createFont(fontName)).toList();
```

How can i fragment a string according to preferredFontList order and their support to display (Font.canDisplay(...)) the codePoints ? [TS_FileTmcrFileHandler.addText(...)](https://github.com/tugalsan/com.tugalsan.lib.file.tmcr/blob/main/src/main/java/com/tugalsan/lib/file/tmcr/server/file/TS_FileTmcrFileHandler.java)

```
//simplified code
var text = "Tuğalsan Karabacak ♠☀☁☃☎☛ ŞşİiIıÜüÖöÇçŞşĞğ";
fragment(text, preferredFontList).forEach((subText, decidedFontIdx)->{
  addText(subText, preferredFontList.get(decidedFontIdx));
});
```

Comment: Are you asking how to create substrings which are each paired with the first font in your Font list which supports all of the corresponding substring’s characters?

Comment: Where are you stuck doing this?

Comment: The frist font is visually good letters. But no symbols. The rest has more symbols. I wish to fragment the text I supply according to the order in the list.

Comment: I can detect which font can display any codepoint with Font.canDisplay function. I can combine multiple codepoints with stringbuilder and create a substring to supply addText function. The problem is after deciding which indexed codepoint is to be rendered with which font, my brain freezes on combining same fonted neigbour codepints to create substrings in a for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of the word “fragment” confused me.  It is not wrong, but it is vague.  I am going to assume that you want break up (fragment) the string into substrings, each of which can be fully rendered by one of your preferred fonts.

A “text run” is a subsequence of characters which all have common attributes.  In this case, that common attribute is the font which will be used to render the characters.  Java has a class which can store text which has attribute-based runs in it:  [AttributedString](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/text/AttributedString.html).

So, we can create a loop which tries calling [Font.canDisplayUpTo](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Font.html#canDisplayUpTo(java.text.CharacterIterator,int,int)) on each font, until that method returns a valid index, indicating that font can display at least one character.  We can use the returned index to not only apply the font to parts of an AttributedString, but also to advance through the string and check the next part of the text with the same font loop, repeating that process until we reach the end of the string:

```
private AttributedString applyFontsTo(String text) {
    AttributedString attrText = new AttributedString(text);

    int len = text.length();
    int textRunStart = 0;
    CharacterIterator i = new StringCharacterIterator(text);
    while (textRunStart >= 0) {
        Font matchingFont = null;
        String runText = null;

        for (Font font : preferredFontList) {
            int textRunEnd = font.canDisplayUpTo(i, textRunStart, len);
            if (textRunEnd != textRunStart) {
                matchingFont = font.deriveFont(24f);
                attrText.addAttribute(TextAttribute.FONT, matchingFont,
                    textRunStart, textRunEnd >= 0 ? textRunEnd : len);

                textRunStart = textRunEnd;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (matchingFont == null) {
            int index = i.getIndex();
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format(
                "Character at index %d (U+%04X) "
                + "cannot be displayed by any of %s",
                index, text.codePointAt(index), preferredFontList));
        }
    }

    return attrText;
}
```

We can now use the AttributedString’s [iterator](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/text/AttributedString.html#getIterator()) in a couple different ways:

- We can render it in a painting method, by passing it to [Graphics.drawString](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawString(java.text.AttributedCharacterIterator,int,int)).
- We can loop through the iterator’s runs using its [getRunLimit](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/text/AttributedCharacterIterator.html#getRunLimit()) method and its inherited [setIndex](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/text/CharacterIterator.html#setIndex(int)) method, to process the text and font in other ways.

Here is an example of the first approach:

```
public void show(String text) {
    AttributedString a = applyFontsTo(text);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1;

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(text.length() * 20, 50);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            ((Graphics2D) g).setRenderingHint(
                RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, 
                RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g.drawString(a.getIterator(), 6, getHeight() - 12);
        }
    };

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Multi-Font Renderer");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

And here is an example of the second approach:

```
public void showAsList(String text) {
    Box box = Box.createVerticalBox();

    AttributedString a = applyFontsTo(text);
    AttributedCharacterIterator i = a.getIterator();
    while (i.getIndex() < i.getEndIndex()) {
        int runLimit = i.getRunLimit();
        String runText = text.substring(i.getIndex(), runLimit);
        Font font = (Font) i.getAttribute(TextAttribute.FONT);

        JLabel label = new JLabel(runText);
        label.setFont(font);
        box.add(label);

        i.setIndex(runLimit);
    }

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Multi-Font Renderer");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(box));
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Here is a complete program which demonstrates both approaches:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import java.text.CharacterIterator;
import java.text.StringCharacterIterator;
import java.text.AttributedCharacterIterator;
import java.text.AttributedString;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontFormatException;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.font.TextAttribute;

import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class MultiFontRenderer {
    private final List<Font> preferredFontList;

    public MultiFontRenderer() {
        preferredFontList = List.of(
            "Roboto-Regular.ttf",
            "FreeSerif.ttf",
            "Quivira.otf",
            "Code2000-rdLO.ttf"
        ).stream().map(fontName -> createFont(fontName)).collect(
            Collectors.toUnmodifiableList());
    }

    private static Font createFont(String name) {
        try (InputStream fontResource =
            MultiFontRenderer.class.getResourceAsStream(name)) {

            return Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, fontResource);
        } catch (IOException | FontFormatException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Cannot load font \"" + name + "\"", e);
        }
    }

    private AttributedString applyFontsTo(String text) {
        AttributedString attrText = new AttributedString(text);

        int len = text.length();
        int textRunStart = 0;
        CharacterIterator i = new StringCharacterIterator(text);
        while (textRunStart >= 0) {
            Font matchingFont = null;
            String runText = null;

            for (Font font : preferredFontList) {
                int textRunEnd = font.canDisplayUpTo(i, textRunStart, len);
                if (textRunEnd != textRunStart) {
                    matchingFont = font.deriveFont(24f);
                    attrText.addAttribute(TextAttribute.FONT, matchingFont,
                        textRunStart, textRunEnd >= 0 ? textRunEnd : len);

                    textRunStart = textRunEnd;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (matchingFont == null) {
                int index = i.getIndex();
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format(
                    "Character at index %d (U+%04X) "
                    + "cannot be displayed by any of %s",
                    index, text.codePointAt(index), preferredFontList));
            }
        }

        return attrText;
    }

    public void show(String text) {
        AttributedString a = applyFontsTo(text);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1;

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(text.length() * 20, 50);
            }

            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                ((Graphics2D) g).setRenderingHint(
                    RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, 
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                g.drawString(a.getIterator(), 6, getHeight() - 12);
            }
        };

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Multi-Font Renderer");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void showAsList(String text) {
        Box box = Box.createVerticalBox();

        AttributedString a = applyFontsTo(text);
        AttributedCharacterIterator i = a.getIterator();
        while (i.getIndex() < i.getEndIndex()) {
            int runLimit = i.getRunLimit();
            String runText = text.substring(i.getIndex(), runLimit);
            Font font = (Font) i.getAttribute(TextAttribute.FONT);

            JLabel label = new JLabel(runText);
            label.setFont(font);
            box.add(label);

            i.setIndex(runLimit);
        }

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Multi-Font Renderer");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(box));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean showList = args.length > 0;

        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            var text = "Tuğalsan Karabacak ♠☀☁☃☎☛ ŞşİiIıÜüÖöÇçŞşĞğ";

            MultiFontRenderer renderer = new MultiFontRenderer();
            if (showList) {
                renderer.showAsList(text);
            } else {
                renderer.show(text);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank u, i will try to implement it. I wish, in the future, there will be simpler answer with the new stream gatherer api. It looks so complex.

Answer (score 0):

I have come with up another solution, using StringBuilder class. [TS_FileTmcrFileHandler.addText(...)](https://github.com/tugalsan/com.tugalsan.lib.file.tmcr/blob/main/src/main/java/com/tugalsan/lib/file/tmcr/server/file/TS_FileTmcrFileHandler.java)

```
//codePoint buffer
var sb = new StringBuilder();

//running all codePoints of the text (a.k.a fullTextThatCanBeDisplayed)
fullTextThatCanBeDisplayed.codePoints().forEachOrdered(cp -> {
    
    //deciding a font according to Font.canDisplay function, if no match found, select idx 0 as defualt
    var decidedFontFamilyIdx = 0;
    for (var fontFamilyIdx = 0; fontFamilyIdx < fontFamilySize; fontFamilyIdx++) {
        if (getFont(fontFamilyIdx).canDisplay(cp)) {
            decidedFontFamilyIdx = fontFamilyIdx;
            break;
        }
    }

    //If new font detected, do steps...
    if (decidedFontFamilyIdx != fileCommonConfig.fontFamilyIdx) {
        
        //step1: send previous data to addText_canDisplay
        if (!sb.isEmpty()) {
            addText_canDisplay(sb.toString());
            sb.setLength(0);
        }

        {//step2: prepare new font
            fileCommonConfig.fontFamilyIdx = decidedFontFamilyIdx;
            setFontStyle();
        }
    }

    //save current codePoint to codePointBuffer
    sb.appendCodePoint(cp);
});

//send lastData to addText_canDisplay
addText_canDisplay(sb.toString());
```

Comment: How is this “using more basic things” when it is relying on non-standard things like “`TGS_Coronator`” and an `addText_canDisplay` method not included? Further, there’s no point in shoehorning the Stream API into everything. Instead of `IntStream.range(0, codePointsSize).forEachOrdered(cpIdx -> {` you can just write `for(int cpIdx = 0; cpIdx < codePointsSize; cpIdx++) {`, to the same effect. And since you’re operating on indices anyway, you can use `substring` instead of copying character by character to a `StringBuilder`…

Comment: I am removing 'for' from my sourcecode as much as possible, to decrease mutating variables. As stream wants effective final variables, It is a bad habit of mine to make things effective final even it is not required to be, by using a callable like coronator. Sorry removing legacy code...

Comment: 'addText_canDisplay' method is parsing the text to lines and send the parsed data to 'addText_line' method. 'addText_line' searches style codes in the text, and send the parsed data to 'addText_do'. 'addText_do' send plain text data to all required file type constructors. There all these things are out of scope of the question.

Comment: About the substring comment, I have looked again, it parses only chars, not codepoints (which can have more than one char) . That is one step low level than what I am dealing with. Ofcourse it can be done, but would you prefer to?

Comment: `substring` does not parse the string at all. If you use codepoint boundary locations only, it will do the right thing. Thinking about it again, your code is wrong. You’re assuming you can iterate from zero to `codePoints().count()` and use the index as argument to [`codePointAt(…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#codePointAt(int)) but unfortunately, the argument to that method is the `char` based index. To process codepoints, you have to iterate from zero to `length()` and skip invalid indices.

Comment: Or, if you keep copying codepoints one by one to a `StringBuilder`, don’t deal with the index at all. You already know about `codePoints()`, so why not use `fullTextThatCanBeDisplayed.codePoints().forEachOrdered(cp -> { … })` in the first place. Then, you have a simplification over the equivalent `for` loop…

Comment: @Holger I did not know that codePointAt(...) uses char indexes. Thanks.